# mysql full text search boolean mode with spaces

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I have select for full text search

```
SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE MATCH(field1, field2, field3, field4) 
AGAINST('C 100 330 00 75*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

C 100 330 00 75 in field2, in field1 the same data but without spaces
C1003300075 ,  in field3 data like "here we are", or "delta star".

Select work for all fields expect for field2 - (C 100 330 00 75) .
So what's wrong? If I remove spaces before search it will affect on another columns. I need search as user will input, with spaces and not spaces.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) **no operator** before words mean:
By default (when neither + nor - is specified) the word is optional, but the rows that contain it are rated higher. This mimics the behavior of MATCH() ... AGAINST() without the IN BOOLEAN MODE modifier.

Answer (score 1):

There are two immediate things wrong.  By default:

- MySQL ignores words shorter than three characters.
- MySQL ignores numbers as words.

You can review the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) on fine-tuning MySQL full text search.  You will need to rebuild the index after you adjust it to store what you want.